# When to remove a potentially colinear regressor

Tags: correlation

I have a pair of regressors ( `donation_amt` & `is_donor`) that don't have a high correlation coefficient ( 0.11) but I'm wondering whether I still need to consider removing one of the two in my analysis because `donation_amt >0` if and only if `is_donor = 1`. This is because they have to be a donor to have a positive donation amount. This also means that if `is_donor = 0` then `donation_amt = 0` and vice versa. If it isn't clear `is_donor` is a binary 1 or 0 and `donation_amt` is continuous.

I think the answer is no because the correlation coefficient is so low but was wondering if I need to consider other reasons like I mentioned above?

Comment: Completely arbitrarily, 'multicollinearity' is defined as a VIF $\ge 10$. With just 2 variables, that requires $r \gtrsim .95$.  You state you have a correlation $r =.11$; that is absolutely nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should keep them, as they provide different piece of information.

Donor says "Is this person a donor?" Donors might differ from non-donors in important ways.

You can also think of this as a non-linear relationship.

Here's an example: The difference between a donor of 1 and a non-donor is 30 on Y. The difference between a donor of 2 and of 1 is 10. So the effect of donation amount depends on whether you are a donor.

```
donor  amount   Y
  0      0      10
  1      1      40
  1      2      50
  1      3      60
```

Comment: It ends up serving as a kind of intercept, whereas the amount gives you a slope-ish object.

Comment: Yeah, nice way of putting it.